# Embed php code in an specific html element with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT Name FROM answer__c where owner__c = 1";
    $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
    $queryResult = new QueryResult($response);

    for ($queryResult->rewind(); $queryResult->pointer < $queryResult->size; $queryResult->next()) {
        echo(); //TODO
    }
?>
```

Basically I'm trying insert the value of the variable into the for statement in a:

```
$("#answers").append("<input type='radio' name='group' /><span>PHP VALUE</span>);
```

Comment: You can try this: $("#answers").append("<input type='radio' name='group' /><span>"+"<?php echo "My Value";?>"+"</span>");

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish, if you can elaborate a little I can attempt an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this if your PHP code has not been already executed on the server.

```
$("#answers").append("<input type='radio' name='group' /><span>"+"<?php echo "My Value";?>"+"</span>");
```

If the page is already rendered and you want to add some PHP code using JQUERY, than you can't accomplish what you want and this will not work because you are adding additional PHP code on the client side which will not be executed.

Hope that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: PHP doesn't work like that. You can't output anything from PHP after the page is passed to the client.

Comment: Who said that it is passes to the client?

Comment: PHP is handled server side. When you visit `index.php` all content and PHP scripts are executed before you see it in your browser. AFTER all PHP has been executed, you get a rendered HTML page for your browser to display. At this point you can manipulate the page with Javascript. By the time you can use JS, you can no longer use PHP, such as echoing a variable.

Comment: You gave me -, but you didn't even read the question! During the page load the code above will work perfectly.

Comment: It depends on the context. The question is not perfectly clear either. Your answer appears to be Javascript trying to append PHP. If you can rework your answer to better explain that I'll gladly reverse my vote.

Comment: I updated my answer, but please read question more patiently ;)

Comment: Right but your code snippet is still reading as Javascript appending string that looks like PHP. Your syntax is for JS, not PHP. For example, in the context of the question it should look more like `echo "$(\"#answers\").append(\"<input type='radio' name='group' /><span>"."My Value"."</span>\");";`

Comment: Create a index.php file and add the following line in the head section: <script>alert("<?php echo "My Value";?>")</script>. Please note that PHP code is inside quotes "". Call this index.php using browser. If you expect that string "<?php echo "My Value";?>" will be printed in the alert window, then you are wrong, because PHP WILL render and it WILL echo "My value" and only "My value" will be printed in the alert window. So what is your point with your last comment?

Comment: My point is, the OPs for loop is in PHP not JS, so you need to echo the JS parts.